# Can't reindex Sunspot SOLR - Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

Everytime i try to reindex using...

> rake sunspot:solr:reindex

These error messages always show:

> Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - retrying...
>   Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - ignoring...
>   Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - retrying...
>   Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - ignoring...

I tried to stop then start using...

```
rake sunspot:solr:stop
rake sunspot:solr:start
```

But nothing happened.

And now everytime I try to run my app in localhost...

This is the error:

```
RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error
Error: Severe errors in solr configuration.

Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.

If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: 

 <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError>

in null

-------------------------------------------------------------

Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:Trip</query></delete>"
```

A more detailed error message than the one I had in terminal.

I tried plenty of solutions from the net like setting Abort Configuration to false, but nothing happened.

The error still persists.

Any work around will be appreciated.

Comment: there is a problem in your configuration file. You would need to check for error during Solr startup to be able to get it working.

Comment: By the way, this was solved already. Thanks for the idea. I restarted my pc and it worked fine

Answer (score 34):

The solution:

1. `rake sunspot:solr:stop`
2. `rm -rvf solr` (Delete your /solr directory)
3. `rake sunspot:solr:start`
4. `rake sunspot:solr:reindex`

Enjoy

Answer (score 6):

Based on the answer provided by @professormeowingtons, what worked for me in production is the following:

1. `$ rake sunspot:solr:stop RAILS_ENV=production`
2. `$ rm -rvf solr # delete your /solr directory`
3. `$ sudo reboot # reboot the machine RAILS_ENV=production`
4. `$ rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production`
5. `$ rake sunspot:solr:reindex RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: $ ps aux | grep solr


ec2-user  1617 12.6  4.4 1618868 76328 ?       Ssl  08:00   0:13 java -Djetty.port=8983 -Dsolr.data.dir=/home/ec2-user/app_name/releases/20150613071155/solr/data/production -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/ec2-user/app_name/releases/20150613071155/solr -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/logging.properties20150613-1617-1q3demw -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar start.jar
ec2-user  1738  0.0  0.0 110268   840 pts/0    S+   08:02   0:00 grep solr

I am getting 404. I tried all possible path in sunspot.yml

Answer (score 4):

With reference to @professormeowingtons, you don't have to delete entire solr directory as you might not want to delete your solr configurations like `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml`. The reason you are getting error might be because of corrupted indexes, what you can do is delete 'solr/env' i.e. `solr/development` or/and `solr/data/development` and restart solr server.

```
 1. rake sunspot:solr:stop

 2. rm -rf solr/development (Delete your solr/development directory)

 3. rm -rf solr/data/development

 4. rake sunspot:solr:start

 5. rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

If problem still persists, rollback your recent changes because you might have added some wrong configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this working by restarting my PC. I guess there was a solr instance incorrectly stopped :-?

Answer (score 0):

This means there is a problem in your config file and solr couldn't start. Check the sunspot logs.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sunspot server by localhost:8982 (depelopment). if you get same error like console. try again by localhost:8983 (production). for my case, port 8983 is work fine and I change sunspot config at rails/config/sunspot.yml to port :8983. and solved.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Rsolr gem to latest version, 1.0.10.pre1, that worked for me.

Now I was able to reindex my models, and everything seems fine, in production that is.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that are using Websolr in Heroku production and getting this error when reindexing:

Remember that you have to upload your schema.xml manually in the Websolr admin GUI, under the "*Advanced Configuration*" tab when viewing your index.
Here's the direct link: `https://websolr.com/slices/<index_uri>/schema`

You can get the `<index_uri>` from running `heroku config` and getting it from the last part of your
WEBSOLR_URL that looks like this: `http://index.websolr.com/solr/<index_uri>`

I ran into this error because I mistakenly assumed that Websolr would just use the `schema.xml` that I committed to git and pushed to heroku together with all the other `<appname>/solr/conf` files.

Answer (score 0):

The essence is to reset every sunspot solr part, that may occur problems.

Delete the complete `solr` directory. **This deletes the complete solr directory for sure - double check!**

```
rm -rf solr
```

Delete the sunspot solr configuration file `config/sunspot.yml`.

```
rm config/sunspot.yml
```

Stop sunspot solr.

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:stop
```

Check if sunspot solr is no longer running. If there are `solr` processes running note there **PID**

```
ps aux | grep solr
```

Manually kill the solr processes by **PID**. This command is only needed if `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:stop` wasn't successful.

```
kill -9 PID # (fully turns off solr - double check `ps aux|grep solr`)
```

Delete your database, **double check if you really sure!** Then recreate the database and restore the schema from the migration files.

```
bundle exec rake db:drop
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

creates a new sunspot configuration `config/sunspot.yml`.

```
rails generate sunspot_rails:install
```

recreates the solr directory

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
```

create a new solr index

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex
```

Finally refill the empty database with your seed data.

```
bundle exec rake db:seed
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: dropping the database should not be a recommended step for a process like this. Users may accidently drop production databases if they follow these steps.